# using LINQ to process a text file

Tags: c#, linq

Text File Format

```
headerinfo = "abc"
**part1=001**
element1
element2....
...
element15
end_element
**part2=002**
element1
element2....
...
emelent15
end_element
......
end_header
```

I want to select all rows of text starting from `part1=001` up to but not including `part2=002`.

So far I have:

```
var res = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(sExecPath + @"\" + sFileName)
           where line == "part1=001"
           select line).ToList();
```

I am trying to use between option in linq, it does not seem to return any result.

```
var part1= (from prt in File.ReadAllLines(sExecPath + @"\" + sFileName)
            where prt.CompareTo("part1=001") >=0  
            && prt.CompareTo("part=002") >= 0
            select prt);
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx):

```
var linesInPartOne = File
       .ReadAllLines(sExecPath + @"\" + sFileName)
       .SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("**part1="))
       // To skip to part 1 header line, uncomment the line below:
       // Skip(1)
       .TakeWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("**part2="));
```

To generalize this to retrieve any given numbered part, something like this would do:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> ReadHeaderPart(String filePath, int part) {
    return File
        .ReadAllLines(filePath)
        .SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("**part" + part + "="))
        // To skip to part 1 header line, uncomment the line below:
        // Skip(1)
       .TakeWhile(line => 
            !line.StartsWith("**part" + (part + 1) + "=" 
            && 
            !line.StartsWith("end_header")))
       .ToList();
 }
```

EDIT: I had a Skip(1) in there to skip the part 1 header.  Removed it since you seem to want to keep that line.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `SkipWhile` to skip all lines to "part1" (just one line in this particular case)?

Comment: ...my guess is that the next question will be "how to get all lines between part2 and part3"... :-)

Comment: Edited to head off that possibility ;-)

Comment: Chris: Why not use a method `ReadFilePart` with parameters `startPart` and `endPart` that could be used for any file? ;-)

Comment: While I'm at it I'll make the function make me coffee in the morning too :-)

Comment: [Apparently Jeff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9087637/284240) had already enough coffee :)

Answer (score 6):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetLinesBetween(
    string path,
    string fromInclusive,
    string toExclusive)
{
    return File.ReadLines(path)
        .SkipWhile(line => line != fromInclusive)
        .TakeWhile(line => line != toExclusive);
}

var path = Path.Combine(sExecPath, sFileName); // don't combine paths like that
var result = GetLinesBetween(path, "part1=001", "part2=002").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and streghtforward solution comes to me is something like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Sample.txt").
             SkipWhile(line=>!line.Contains("part1")).
                   Skip(1).TakeWhile(line=>!line.Contains("part2"));
```

It returns result you want actually. 
The logic is simple:

- `SkipWhile` lines till meeting a line that contains "part1"
- after `Skip(1)` (as it will be actually that one that contains "part1" string)
- finally `Take` those ones till getting to the line containing "part2".

Comment: I tried this since it uses few lines of code :-). Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Linq probably isn't your best bet here. Just try doing

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
List<string> linesICareABout = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; !linesICareAbout[i].Contains("part2=002"); ++i)
{
 linesICareABout.Add(lines[i]);
}
```

Then do whatever you want with the lines you read in.

However, if you're really dedicated to using Linq, try TakeWhile

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx