# How to read a text file line by line on click of a button in c#

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

I would like to read a text-file line by line. But, what I want to do is everytime the button is clicked it reads the next line and insert it into a textbox. So until the button is clicked it doesn't insert the next line into the text box.

[code]

```
    int lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").Length;
    int count = 0;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\test.txt");


        if (lineCount > count)
        {
            textBox1.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            count++;
        }
    }
```

// When I click the button more than once nothing happens with this code.

Comment: That's because you're reading the whole file on each click, you are also trying to read from the console on a windows application.  It does not suspend a windows app.

Comment: I'm writing to the text box though

Comment: Did you try to step through your code using the debugger? It would make clear to you that your line counter is reset and your reading the whole file every time.

Comment: @Filburt should I have to check how many lines the text file has first?

Comment: Check out [using LINQ to process a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9087452/205233) - in your case you'd `.Skip(counter)` and `.Take(1)` ... and counter should be a field outside your button1_Click handler.

Answer (score 2):

you should define the StreamReader as a field of your class:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;

    if (file == null)
        file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
    if (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = file.ReadLine();
        textBox1.Text = line;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("End");
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: global? there are no globals in c#. Looks like you mean define it as a field. Also, why set it to null? Just go ahead and initialize it in the field intializer. Also you can delete those `counter` and `line` variables.

Comment: Yes :D Yes :D Yes :D all of you told is true, I answer it so so so fact, Excuse me. @GeorgeMauer I edit this